# How to fix this code for "decimal to binary" in c#

Tags: c#, algorithm, binary, decimal, formula

I have a problem with outputting formulas from the binary formula in c#

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("Input number : ");
            int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("The Formula : ");

            int accommodate = 0;

            for (int i = num; i > 0; i /= 2)
            {
                if (num % i == 0)
                {
                    accommodate++;

                    if (accommodate == 2)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(i + "/2 = 0");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(i + "/2 = 1" );
                    }

                }
            }
             Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

the output is

Input number : 12

The Formula :

12/2 = 1 "(X) this is wrong, it should be 0"

6/2 = 0

3/2 = 1

1/2 = 1

Comment: What is `accommodate ` for?

Comment: What should the code do? What does it do? What exactly is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this

`accommodate % 2` instead `accommodate % i`

Set `accommodate = i /= 2` in for loop instead of `accommodate++`

```
Console.Write("Input number : ");
            int num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("The Formula : ");

            int accommodate = 0;

            for (int i = num; i > 0; accommodate = i /= 2)
            {
                if (accommodate % 2 == 0)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine(i + "/2 = 0");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(i + "/2 = 1");
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
```